# How to change the text color of a Vuetify button?

Tags: vuetify.js

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out the proper way to change the text color in a `v-btn`. This works, but having to use `!important` doesn't seem ideal:

```css
.v-btn
    color: red !important
```

The `color` prop is only for the background color, as far as I'm aware. And I guess I could change the theme primary/secondary when calling `Vue.use(Vuetify, { theme: {...}} )`, but what if I want to override a single component?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

There are [css classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/colors#classes) for coloring text anywhere in vuetify, just append `--text` to a color.
So for example

```
<v-btn class="red--text">
```

It should work with colors defined in your theme as well e.g. `primary--text` and similar.
Note that this is not specific to a `v-btn`, class should work anywhere.

Comment: ah, got it. How about if I want to use a random color like "#1976D2"? Do I need to make it a primary/secondary or something like that first?

Comment: @nachocab Yes I believe that is the proper way thus far. However you might not want to use "random" colors but instead try to use what is already available to you by framework if possible: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/src/stylus/settings/_colors.styl

Comment: Right. That makes sense. I was just wondering how I would change another property, like font-family or something like that. I don't think they have specific classes for every possible value

Comment: You are in for a [surprise](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/typography) :) Not a font-family but surely a lot of options.

Comment: Updated link https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#classes. I found this answer very helpful.

Comment: Can this be combined with `darken-x` and `lighten-x` classes?

Comment: @dotNET Yes, for example add `text--darken-4`

Answer (score 13):

If you are using `vuetify` you may seems like to apply this as a standard color:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";
    
Vue.use(Vuetify);
    
export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: "#14C6FF",
        secondary: "#424242",
        accent: "#82B1FF",
        error: "#FF5252",
        info: "#2196F3",
        success: "#4CAF50",
        warning: "#FFC107",
        lightblue: "#14c6FF",
        yellow: "#FFCF00",
        pink: "#FF1976",
        orange: "#FF8657",
        magenta: "#C33AFC",
        darkblue: "#1E2D56",
        gray: "#909090",
        neutralgray: "#9BA6C1",
        green: "#2ED47A",
        red: "#FF5c4E",
        darkblueshade: "#308DC2",
        lightgray: "#BDBDBD",
        lightpink: "#FFCFE3",
        white: "#FFFFFF"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and can be easily access using `color="lightpink"` prop or whatever you like.

Comment: This is the best way to deal with common theme contents

Answer (score 2):

Using VueJs 3 and Vuetify 3, the classes --text didn't work for me but the following worked fine:

```
<v-btn 
    color  = "light-blue-lighten-3"
    @click = "isSnackBar03Open = true">

    <span class = "text-white">
        Open 03
    </span>

</v-btn>
```

This one worked too:

```
<v-btn 
    color  = "light-blue-lighten-3"
    class  = "text-white"
    @click = "isSnackBar03Open = true">

    <span>
        Open 03
    </span>

</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of the text entered in the span existing in the button. In this way:

```css
v-btn {
    border-radius: 8px !important;
    border-color: red !important;
    color: red  !important;
    background-color: red !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    max-width: auto;
    font-size-adjust: auto;
    margin: 1px;

    &:hover {
        background-color: blue !important;
        color: blue !important;
        text-decoration-color: blue !important;
        border-color: blue !important;
        margin: 1px;
        span {
            color: white !important;
        }
    }
}
```